# Migrating from ASP.NET 4.6.2 to ASP.NET Core 6

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, migration

As the title suggests, I have been migrating over a project and once I did, the whole layout is not how it was with ASP.NET 4.6.2.

Has anyone ran into this issue before where the layout is out of whack while migrating and if so how was the issue rectified?

Thanks

Comment: was is this a webforms application? You can't use web forms in .net core. So, if this was a .net 4.6 MVC application, then fine - it should work quite well. However, if this was a webforms applcation, then you can't do this at all. You would be better to convert (re-write) the applcation as MVC in .net 4.6, and THEN make a conversion to .net core which in theory would and should go quite seamless and be easy.  In fact, if you converting from webforms to MVC, then start the new project as .net core.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal, Its MVC. I'll have to keep digging around to see if any CSS files were left behind. I wasn't doing the migration, so its possible that something may have been missed...Something is awry.

Comment: Maybe you missed something when [migrating your layout files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/mvc?view=aspnetcore-6.0#migrate-the-layout-files).